# Making a region-indent-function keep the region marked

Tags: emacs, elisp, indentation

I'm having trouble with haml-mode's `region-indent-function`, which I'm trying to reuse in another major mode. We're supposed to be able to cycle the region indentation by keeping the region marked after the haml-indent-region is being evaled, but it doesn't work as intended. After some hacking around, I've found out that throwing an error at the end of the function makes Emacs keep the region marked, as in this example:

```
(defun haml-indent-region (start end)
  (save-excursion
    ...)
  (error "")) ;; Terrible hack
```

But I really don't like it. Is there a clean way of getting this behavior without such an horrible hack?

Comment: I do not understand. `save-excursion` should save and restore both point and mark; i.e., the region...  Throwing an error should have nothing to do with it.  Is this not the behavior you observe?

Comment: It should, but here I'm suspecting that it how Emacs handle a major mode indent-region-function that is the issue. It's after this function has been called (without error) that the region is unmarked. At least that's what I'm seeing from my tests.

Comment: Maybe the mark is still set but just getting "deactivated"?  Have you tried using `(activate-mark)` to re-activate the mark (and thus highlight the region)?

Comment: That doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The region is reset *after* the command completes, so calling activate-mark does not have any effect. Throwing an error (a non-local exit) apparently prevents this step, but that might be a bug.

The trick is: `deactivate-mark`

> If an editing command sets this to t, deactivate the mark afterward.
>   The command loop sets this to nil before each command,
>   and tests the value when the command returns.
>   Buffer modification stores t in this variable.

So just do this at the end of your command:

```
  (setq deactivate-mark nil)
```

Comment: As of emacs 24.3.1 at least, `indent-region' calls `(deactivate-mark)` directly, without querying the `deactivate-mark` variable. Hence when changing indentation behaviour by setting the value of `indent-line-function` or `indent-region-function`, doesn't allow preserving highlighted region.